# Help sourcing a quote - "There is no doctrine so invalid..."

Tags: knowledge, skepticism, quote, berkeley

Recently a quote popped into my head, which I recall as a Bishop Berkeley proposition. But on further looking into the matter, I can't seem to find it. It's within the general area of the following: 
"There is no opinion so invalid, no doctrine so false, that it does not contain a modicum of truth." 
All leads and suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I did searches on Google and DuckDuckGo. They both found nothing. Is that an exact quote?

Comment: @MarkAndrews no - just how I remember it

Comment: I made a 2nd attempt with a search engine. Again, no luck. I suggest some plain old book research on this question.

Answer (score 4):

I happened on the answer to your question.

The quotation is "Nihil tam absurde dici potest quod non dicatur ab aliquo filosophorum" (There is nothing so absurd but some philosopher has said it - Cicero, De Divinatione, II, 58.

I found this at [Phil. Stack Exchange - Question Which kinds of philosophical arguments are more than subjective opinions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/100104/which-kinds-of-philosophical-arguments-are-more-than-subjective-opinions)

I confirmed it at [Imperium Romanum - Quotes of Cicero](https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/roman-art-and-culture/golden-thoughts-of-romans/quotes-of-cicero/)